# throwing error 'std::bad_alloc', OpenCL For CPU and not GPU

Tags: c, exception, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

So i m running matrix multiplication OpenCL code, 
Problem is the same code, is running like a charm in GPU, but give the error for CPU.
The Error i m getting is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
   what():  std::bad_alloc
 Command terminated by signal 6
```

The code i m using being referenced from this link,

http://gpgpu-computing4.blogspot.com/2009/09/matrix-multiplication-2-opencl.html

i have made slight changes as per my requirements, otherwse the code is pretty much same.
can anyone help me out why is the error coming.

thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't look like an error a C program would give you. C dosn't have exceptions or namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Is this exception being thrown before, during, or after kernel execution? Can you narrow down what line this exception is being thrown on?

Are you running this on a large array? One thing that comes to mind is that you're running out of memory when you launch on the CPU. This might seem odd at first because your CPU probably has more memory available to it than your GPU, but keep in mind that if you're executing on the CPU you're storing each buffer in CPU memory twice - once for the host-side setup code and once for the device-side kernel code. On the other hand, if you execute on the GPU then your main CPU memory holds one copy of the buffer (host side) while your GPU memory holds the other (used by kernel on device). Basically your CPU is both your host and device when it runs OpenCL kernels, so make sure that all your buffers (host side and device side) fit into its memory.

Comment: the exception is thrown before the kernel execution, yeah i m running it on a large array, but even when i m trying to run it on smaller arrays, its giving the same problem.

Comment: Can you point out _exactly_ where the exception is thrown (i.e. what line)? It's tough to be of much help without knowing where in the code this problem occurs.